# What is the cause of my loud engine and how do I fix it?

Tags: chevrolet

I drive an 09 Chevy Malibu. I’m young and live with a single mother, so it’s hard to get some help on this topic and research has lead me to so many places. My car has ran fine up until this fall/winter. The car’s Accleration has decreased, so when I try to speed up on the highway it’s incredibly slower than before. Sometimes it gets hard to break 60, I really have to push on the pedal. Also the pedal will vibrate, more the faster I go, sending vibrations up my leg. The engine noise will be incredibly loud too, louder than my radio that I will blast. There used to be humming coming from the engine, but it’s seemed to stop and only be a loud rumbling engine. 
To sum it up, my engine is very loud and the gas pedal vibrates a lot. My car can not accelerate at a normal speed, it takes a while for it to kick in and start going faster, and the engine sounds like it’s about to have a heart attack it’s working so hard. My rmps seem to be running higher worand jumps around unlike it has before. Also!! My gas tank, it drains soooo fast( do not know if it’s related, but I drive the speed limit and break lightly and drive only to school and work). 
Thank you. Someone just lead me in the right direction(:

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering if there is any way to get a video of what the car sounds like while sitting and then while driving? Descriptive words can only go so far some times. Also, is the Check Engine Light (CEL) on? If so, is there anyway you could take it by an AutoZone or Advance Auto (or pretty much any major auto chain store) to get the codes read? These would be invaluable in us helping you get this sorted.

Comment: Also, a good first thing to check would be to look at your fluid levels in the engine compartment -- your oil especially, but also you could look at the coolant level and transmission fluid level if you can find them.  How long has it been since you had an oil change on this car?

Answer (score 1):

The bearings in the engine are worn out, or the piston rings on one or more cylinders are bad. This could have been caused by lack of oil or the oil being to thick for winter.

- If it is the bearings, they maybe able to be replaced without taking the motor out.
- If it is the rings, the engine either needs a rebuild or to be replaced.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure how you went from "loud engine noise" to the engine needing replaced? Seems there's a lot more diagnostics in between there and where you went. I mean, it could be a busted exhaust pipe. We don't know yet as there's not enough information.